# My javascript won't work as it should

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create a website in HTML which recieves JSON-formatted data using javascript and, then it will be injecting that data into my website.

The problem is I can't find any errors. I used this [example code](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/). To get data from my webserver into my HTML. I established a connection to my database using a example linked above. But then I wanted to move that existing code into this example [over here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/).

In the example above, I've linked my javascript file which fetches the data and creates a div with the a `id`, the same `id` which is assigned in the javascript file that fetches the data. But it won't work at all. In the `div` that would be filled with data, is just empty.

fetch.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
                + item.longitude+'</p>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.')
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a live demo, the code is loading when it's online on a webserver. But not when it's local. What is causing this?

http://codele.se/app/flip/debatt.html

Comment: Please give details of what you have and *why* it doesn't work. Simply saying 'it doesn't work' is helping no one.

Comment: By 'details' Rory meant the actual code too I think.

Comment: @ppeterka the code would be the 'what you have' :)

Comment: dont give link post your js here

Comment: I have no clue, it should work. But it doesn't, I tried re-writing all code, no success. I can't see whats causing the problem.

Comment: @Jack Put your *exact* code into the question above. Show your work. Also: please post an example of your JSON data.

Comment: What exactly is not working? javascript? mysql_query ? 
does your query returns the data?

Comment: The JSON won't be returned at all. 
I will be uploading the code, hold on. @Pratik

Comment: @PenguinCoder Here's all the code. Swipe left with your cursor!

Comment: What do you mean by "local"?

Comment: By "local" I mean that I should be able to retrieve the data by opening a HTML-file from my desktop on a PC instead of opening a ex. "http://stackoverflow.com/blabla.html" @epascarello

Comment: I am able to retrieve the data by opening a HTML-file from my desktop on a PC... I mean "local"

Comment: Hold on, will be checking on my friends pc. @Pratik

Comment: hey can you show your HTML ?

Comment: The file is being run from c:/foo.html and you are trying to access http://...? What browser?

Comment: codele.se/app/flip/debatt.html @Pratik

Comment: file:///C:/Users/nti/Dropbox/ST%20Flip/debatt.html in the lastest Chrome on Windows 7. @epascarello

Comment: where you have added JS file in this HTML?

Comment: Ok So you got what you want !! Coool

Answer (score 1):

Mixing file and http is a bad because of increased security rules. I have a feeling that is the problem here. You can start up chrome so it is less strict with security rules.

Try

```
chrome.exe -–allow-file-access-from-files
```

or

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

or kiosk mode

```
chrome.exe  --enable-kiosk-mode
```

Comment: Did not help, will be looking into this a bit deeper.

Answer (score 1):

On using firebug on your site i found out that your html contains updated data as shown here:

[image: Code]

The problem is you are using background image that hides it on removing this line of code from your site:

```
<div style="z-index: 3; left: 512px; transform: rotateY(0deg);" class="page cover">
```

I get this output:

[image: output]

on having a closer look I found that you have two div in html that have the same ID output, so make it sure that only one div has the `output` id bcoz ID should be unique in html.

[image: error]

Comment: If so, why does the code show in my live demo? Text inside that CSS rules shows if I'm creating a <p>HelloWorld</p> @Zaheer Ahmed

Comment: Will try, I'll be coming to notify you about how it went @Zaheer Ahmed

Comment: check it now duplicate ID can be your problem.

Comment: If the data isn't visible due to my CSS, why doesn't even the HTML show?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or some other browser developer tool) and in a Firebug console check errors and data received from server.

Edit:
Okay. You posted your JS code.
Your code looks OK. Data from server is received.
If you see nothing after running this. Probably you have malformed HTML. Is in your page a div element or something other with id="output"?

Comment: Your 'answer' should be a comment.

Comment: Already checked that. There is **only** one DIV-tag with the "id="output"

Comment: Okay. Your code works - checked on page that you posted. But div with id="output" is covered by div with class="front". So you can't see content of <div id="output">
This is reason why to use Firebug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If this code is not working correctly for you, there must be something else going on. Per [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw3J4/) the code works fine.

Check to make sure you have a div with the id of `output` in your HTML, and that you're actually including the script `fetch.js` on your page.  Check the JS console of your browsers developer tools for other errors.

Edit: Your CSS image placement and `h1` tag attributes are causing the data to not be displayed correctly. If I change the `h1` to `h2` in your CSS, the headers (such as 'Big Ben') show up properly. However, as there is no scrolling for your div `output`, and the image div `img-cont img-1` and div `front` are covering up part of your `output` you won't ever see that entire text.

This is a CSS/layout issue, not a Javascript issue. Fix your CSS.

Comment: It's "outputting" as I want for now, but not when the file is local. And that's my concern.

Comment: Do you have a PHP page returning the exact JSONP format as the http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php page?? Show that code and its output in your question above.

Comment: The PHP page I have returns the exact data as http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php does.

Comment: I will be trying to edit it to get everything working alright. Thanks!

Comment: But, if that'se the problem. Why won't it work when i open the HTML-file from my desktop? @PenguinCoder

Comment: @Jack not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want the HTML-file to retrieve the JSON data if I'm opening the HTML-file from my C:/ folder ex. @PenguinCoder

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to implement JSONP which is a method to request data from a server in a different domain. Your data source (usually webservice) should be told to wrap its response with a function call around it. If you're data source didn't wrap the response then your client cannot receive the response if deployed to live environment although locally it works.

Here's what you can do if you have control or if you can modify your data source functions. (If not it's impossible to implement JSONP). The data source in my example is a REST Service.

//Data Source (REST Service)

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getdata?callback={callback}&testParam1={p1}&testParam2={p2}")]
    public void GetData(string testParam1, string testParam2, string callback)
    {
        //Callback method is one of the parameters
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        var data = _db.GetRecords(testParam1, testParam2);
        //wrap the response 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}( {{ result:\"{1}\"}} )", callback, data));
    }
```

//Client Implementation

```
function GetMainMarket(holder, template, testParam1, testParam2) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:2520/DataServices/getdata',
    data: { testParam1: 'test1', testParam2: 'test2' },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        eval(data.result);
        var output = $(template).parseTemplate(json);
        $('#' + holder).html(output);
    }
});
```

};