# returning Json result from WFC service and using the result in $.ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, jquery

I have an asp.net page where I am using jquery ajax. I need to create a method which I can use as url in $.ajax. I did search on net and found that I need to create WCF service. My solution is in asp.net 3.5. I have created two methods in IJsonDataService.cs interface like this

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IJsonDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Person DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();
    }

and then in class file I have implemented them like this:

   [WebGet(RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate="data/{id}")]
 public Person DoWork(){
 return new Person();
```

}

```
 [WebGet(RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate="data/{id}")]
    public string GetData(string parameter)
    {
        return "this is" + abc;
    }
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="JsonDataServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="JsonDataServiceBehavior" name="JsonDataService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IJsonDataService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I want to pass Id to these methods and then query database and return results and then format the results as json and retun that json back to $.ajax method. What change do I need to make in above methods and how can i return data as json and then use it in $.ajax? Please suggest.

Comment: Your endpoint binding needs to be webHttpBinding rather than wsHttpBinding.

Comment: Also you would need to include the appropriate serviceBehavior

Answer (score 0):

here are couple of articles tutorials i found to be usefull

http://geekswithblogs.net/Nettuce/archive/2009/10/18/wcf-jquery-rest-json-service.aspx

this one was most useful

http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/

Comment: why my config file looks different from all the tutorials. Doesnt web.config change automatically when I create WCF service ?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this. This approach is similar to what you want to accomplish.

[Web Service in MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870187/web-service-in-mvc-app/14870436#14870436)

If you want to have a sample JSONP see [My javascript won't work as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318816/my-javascript-wont-work-as-it-should/14319318#14319318)

Comment: @robert I have asp.net web form application not MVC also, I need json response.

Comment: It's not about MVC or Webform. It's about calling WebService using ajax which is not allowed in a cross-domain policy but in that Link I pointed out that it's possible only by using JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Your config needs to look like something below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="json">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="JsonDataServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="JsonDataServiceBehavior" name="JsonDataService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="namespace.IJsonDataService">                       
                </endpoint>                    
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```